# Python does not play mp4 and avi files

Tags: python, mp4, vlc, codec

This program does not play videos but the sound is okey.
I get an error about h264 or MJPG.When trying to play an .mp4 or .avi file I see the this messages.

> main decoder error: Codec `MJPG' (Motion JPEG Video) is not supported.
>
> main decoder error: Codec not supported
>
> main decoder error: VLC could not decode the format "MJPG" (Motion
>   JPEG Video)

or

> main decoder error:Codec `h264' (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)) is not
>   supported.
>
> main decoder error: Codec not supported
>
> main decoder error: VLC could not decode the format "h264" (H264 -
>   MPEG-4 AVC (part 10))

and this is my code

```
import vlc

from time import sleep


Instance = vlc.Instance('--fullscreen')
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('/home/onur/video_005.avi') #Media Location
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()

sleep(5) # Or however long you expect it to take to open vlc

while player.is_playing():
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: what is your OS, show your complete error message as text. How did you install vlc?

Comment: I downloaded vlc from ubuntu software store.

--this is error message:
[00007fa51c011b40] main decoder error: Codec `MJPG' (Motion JPEG Video) is not supported.
[00007fa51c011b40] main decoder error: Codec not supported
[00007fa51c011b40] main decoder error: VLC could not decode the format "MJPG" (Motion JPEG Video)

Comment: 1) I ask about the python vlc library and not the vlc player. Have you used conda / anaconda to install it? 2) The error message should be in your question, not as an image but as text, and it should not be in the comments. 3) What version of ubuntu do you use?

Comment: 1)ı use pıp3 , yes  ı used anaconda 3)19.10

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav ffmpeg`

Comment: libav is already the newest version